# Cannot get Google Analytics (GA4) Realtime to Work

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4, google-ads-script

**Hello Community!**

A friend hired me for SEO implementation and a re-design for his website ( https://intercosultores.net). Among these implementations comes the integration for Google Analytics, GA4.

***For Context:***
The site has been mounted on Wordpress and previously he had used Google Ads for his website, that's why he inserted a Global Site Tag and a Remarketing Tag with a snippet plugin to add these.

***The issue is:***
I've created a property for this website within Google Analytics and created a standard Data Stream as I've always done for any other web, copied the Global Site Tag and placed it in the head tag of the website as usual. The problem is, after a while, I'm still not able to view any realtime users even if I'm navigating in it and blocking my ID is not a setting so I should appear. (I'm not using any ad-blocker of any sort which could interfere with the script)

I've tried other options to mounting the GA tag such as through Google Tag Manager and still the same result. Also through the Jetpack pluggin for wordpress which only asks for the Measurement ID and still the same result...

Could there be a problem with the GA Tag and the Global Site Tag from Google Ads?

By the way, the google ads account is of my client, my plan as it has worked before is to set up the property of Analytics and then transfer it later on (we have that trust) but I don't know why this simple task is having such a persistent issue.

Thanks in advance for any advice, really appreciate it!!

Comment: I'm having a similar problem but in my case I'm sending the events via the API. Are you seeing the events in the reports->engagement->events report? i.e. is it just the real-time report failing. In configuration->events are existing events being added. Note that it can take 24 hours for those reports to show anything.

Comment: Hey Tony, Thank you for your reply!! At the moment I'm just placing the snippet inside my html in the head tag, not using any API for this matter. The weird thing is, it is recording the events. Apparently it must be a real-time report fail since as you highlight, it's actually taking maybe up to 24 hours to show data. It just worries me since I'm not receiving a realtime report, could it be a problem from my end such as conflicting Global Site Tags or is it an issue on Google's Ga4 part plain and simple? I could rest easy jus knowing data will be collected accurately later on.

Comment: A few others have said they have the same problem. No real-time but the events are in reports. One person suggested we use the feedback option (bottom right). I've done that.